# UnsupportedOperationException thrown by custom library

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-library

I'm trying to use this library [Android-Target-Tooltip](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip), in particular I'm trying to show popup message from button into toolbar, here what I've done:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
{
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "Info").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_outline_black_30dp)
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Tooltip.make(getApplicationContext(),
                    new Tooltip.Builder(102)
                            .anchor(menu.findItem(0).getActionView(), Tooltip.Gravity.BOTTOM)
                            .closePolicy(new Tooltip.ClosePolicy()
                                    .insidePolicy(true, false)
                                    .outsidePolicy(true, false), 10000)
                            .text("This is text")
                            .maxWidth(800)
                            .withArrow(true)
                            .withOverlay(true)
                            .build()
            ).show();
            return false;
        }
    }).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

But when I click it throws **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010093 a=1236}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:459)
at it.sephiroth.android.library.tooltip.TooltipOverlayDrawable.<init>(TooltipOverlayDrawable.java:54)
at it.sephiroth.android.library.tooltip.TooltipOverlay.init(TooltipOverlay.java:25)
at it.sephiroth.android.library.tooltip.TooltipOverlay.<init>(TooltipOverlay.java:37)
at it.sephiroth.android.library.tooltip.Tooltip$TooltipViewImpl.<init>(Tooltip.java:472)
at it.sephiroth.android.library.tooltip.Tooltip.make(Tooltip.java:71)
at com.android.launcher3.SettingsActivity$1.onMenuItemClick(SettingsActivity.java:83)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:167)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The element at index value 1 (the 2nd element in the array) does not support the getColor method.

Comment: @DwB Yes but it is bug of library...

Comment: @MicheleLacorte could it be that you passed it something it wasn't expecting ? which line in your code triggers it ? did you set a theme ?

Comment: Look for a `TooltipOverlay` in your styles xml, I suspect it's missing a 'color' attribute. Something like: https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip/blob/master/library/src/main/res/values/styles.xml#L17

Comment: @MicheleLacorte The Android documentation for [TypedArray.getColor] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.htm).  Provides the answer to why you received the exception:
**Throws UnsupportedOperationException if the attribute is defined but is not an integer color or color state list.**

Comment: @Sticks I read that but I can't understand how to fix..how this value missed? Maybe in style.xml I have to define TooltipDefualtStyle?

Comment: @MicheleLacorte I have not used the library in question but they provide an example [here](https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip)

Comment: I can't figure out...

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?